Difference between extern on a variable and a const variable
The "extern" keyword is like a forward declaration or a non-defined/implemented function signature.
It says "there is this variable, and it may be located in another translation unit, BUT I'M NOT DEFINING IT HERE".
const variables have internal linkage. If I want it to have external linkage I have to put "extern" on it:
extern const int my_constant = 7;

Right? And "extern" here has completely different meaning, it basically means "export to other translation units", right?
And so you have the case where the "forward declaration" looks like:
extern const int my_constant;

And the definition looks like:
extern const int my_constant = 7;

Meaning the distinguishing thing between forward declaration and definition with a const type is simple the initialisation, right? Put another way:
"extern" on a non const variable is a forward declaration, "extern" on a const variable means "export" 

Right?

"Meaning the distinguishing thing between forward declaration and definition with a const type is simple the initialisation, right?": It is not specific to const. That applies to all variable declarations with extern.

@user17732522 Oh right. So extern on a const simply means "export". What about extern int a = 7;  The extern does nothing, that's the same as int a = 7;

Yes, extern is redundant in that one but has the same meaning: Make the variable have external linkage (which is the default though in this case) and, if there is no initializer, don't make it a definition (but there is one).

I wish there was a nice C++ cheatsheet of what the implicit qualifiers and specifiers are in the different contexts and scenarios.  There's too frippin' many of them to keep straight.  They "just work"... until they don't.
